# Java 8: How does `QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD=286` comes from?

Tags: java, arrays

In Java 8, function `Arrays.sort()` depends on the length of array;

```
if(length>=`QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD=286`){
    take `Dual-Pivot Quicksort`;
}
else if(length<`QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD=286` && length>`INSERTION_SORT_THRESHOLD=47`){
    take `One-Pivot Quicksort
}
else { take `Insertion Sort`}
```

How does the `286` or `47` comes from?

Comment: A heck of a lot of performance tests probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the calculation of the complexity of the algorithm.

Some infos here on StackOverflow:
[How to optimize quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454866/how-to-optimize-quicksort)

Merge sort:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/merge-sort/a/analysis-of-merge-sort

Quick sort:
https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/quick-sort/a/analysis-of-quicksort

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort is faster than quick sort for smaller arrays because there are less constant-factor overheads involved. Same with the single-pivot vs dual-pivot. We need to find out at what point this is to get these numbers.

They probably tried a range of numbers and then ran performance tests for each of them, and kept the numbers with the best performance.