# Python idiom to get same result as calling os.path.dirname multiple times?

Tags: python, build, filepath, os.path, dirname

I find myself needing to get a parent directory of a python file in a source tree that is multiple directories up with some regularity. Having to call dirname many times is clunky.

I looked around and was surprised to not find posts on this.

The general scenario is:

```
import os.path as op
third_degree_parent = op.dirname(op.dirname(op.dirname(op.realpath(__file__))))
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this that doesn't require nested dirname calls?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Normalize a relative path; [`os.pardir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.pardir) is the parent directory, repeat it as many times as needed. It is available via `os.path.pardir` too:

```
import os.path as op

op.abspath(op.join(__file__, op.pardir, op.pardir, op.pardir))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. As a follow up, what if any corner cases does that approach suffer from?

Comment: @TimWilder: None that I can think of right now; if you find any, let me know and I'll see how we could tackle those.

Comment: I'm thinking of issues with symlinks; I'd need to think about the interaction between the op.join approach and paths/do some reading to explore that one more fully. The general concern is along the lines of os.path.abspath vs. os.path.realpath.

Comment: @TimWilder: `realpath` uses `abspath` under the hood, so feel free to replace the call.

Comment: Good to know. I feel like this is an improvement on clarity and conciseness from the dirname calls, so thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't using os.pardir be more portable? Something like  op.abspath(op.join(__file__, os.pardir, os.pardir, os.pardir))

Answer (score 6):

Since it has not been demonstrated yet, here is an answer using a [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3093) function.

**Function**

```
import os
def parent(path, level = 0):
    parent_path = os.path.dirname(path)
    if level == 0:
        return parent_path
    return parent(parent_path, level - 1)
```

**Explaination**

- get the dirname of a path that is input
- if the level is not 0, function calls itself, causing it to get the dirname of the dirname
- process repeats recursively until level has reached 0

**Example**

```
>>> parent('/my/long/path/name/with/a/file.txt')
'/my/long/path/name/with/a'
>>> parent('/my/long/path/name/with/a/file.txt', 0)
'/my/long/path/name/with/a'
>>> parent('/my/long/path/name/with/a/file.txt', 4)
'/my/long'
```

Comment: Short, sweet, and interpretable! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Someone else added an answer in 2018, 4 years later, so why not add mine.  The other answers are either long or become long if a larger number of parents are required.  Let's say you need 7 parents.  This is what I do

```
os.path.abspath(__file__ + 8 * '/..')
```

Note the extra (8=7+1) to remove 7 parents as well as the file name.  No need for `os.path.pardir` as `abspath` understands `/..` universally and will do the right thing.  Also has the advantage that the number of parents can be dynamic, determined at run-time.

In comparison, the equivalent using the accepted answer (longer and less obvious):

```
import os.path as op
op.abspath(op.join(__file__, op.pardir, op.pardir, op.pardir, op.pardir, op.pardir, op.pardir, op.pardir))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def updir(d, n):
  """Given path d, go up n dirs from d and return that path"""
  ret_val = d
  for _ in range(n):
    ret_val = os.path.dirname(ret_val)
  return ret_val
```

Given a directory `d = '/path/to/some/long/dir'` you can use the above function to go up as many levels as you want. For example:

```
updir(d,0)
'/path/to/some/long/dir'
updir(d,1)
'/path/to/some/long'
updir(d,2)
'/path/to/some'
updir(d,3)
'/path/to'
updir(d,4)
'/path'
```

Comment: Please add a little explanantion in your answer to help people understand better.

Comment: I added an explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I will extend the accepted answer with N

```
import os.path as op

op.abspath(op.join(__file__, \*N\*[op.pardir]))
```