# Why is my javascript code going into an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

In the code below, whenever I click on the submit button, multiple window's open up as it it were in infinite loop. If I uncomment alert, then multiple alerts keep popping like they were in infinite loop. Why could this be happening ?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    var window;

    function moveBy() {
        //alert("-- hello ---");
        window = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
        window.moveBy(10, 20);
    }
</script>


</head>
<body>
<input type = "submit" value = "moveBy" onclick = "moveBy()"> </input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a three line function and can't see why it's looping infinitely?

Comment: When you declare a function in the global scope, it attaches to the `window` object in the browser. That said, you create a function called `moveBy` then call it within itself.

Comment: You can't assign a new value to `window`. `window = ....` doesn't change the value of `window`, so the `window` in the last line of your function is still the global `window` object.

Comment: When you use recursion in js you must always have an exit case to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: The easiest solution is to name your function something other than an [existing method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/moveBy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a [recursion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwbyhkx4(v=vs.94).aspx) (function that calls itself) by calling `window.moveBy` inside your `moveBy` function without stating a break point or exit case:

```
function moveBy() {
    //alert("-- hello ---");
    window = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
    window.moveBy(10, 20); //recursion, it will call this function over and over again.
}
```

Maybe what you want is to use another name for your function and call the actual `window.moveBy` inside with predefined parameters:

```
function customMoveBy() {
    //alert("-- hello ---");
    window = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
    window.moveBy(10, 20);
}

<input type = "submit" value = "moveBy" onclick = "customMoveBy()"> </input>
```

Answer (score 8):

Javascript does not support method overloading, so by calling `window.moveBy(10, 20);` you are actually basically calling `moveBy()` again, resulting in an infinite loop.

Calling a function from itself is called [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it). The linked post is a good read on this topic, and will guide you on where you might *want* it. But in your case you clearly don't.

Have a read of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/797997/JavaScript-does-NOT-support-Method-Overloading-Tha) article for more detail.

**To prevent this from happening**, you can rename your `moveBy()` function to `myMoveBy()` or better `openAndMoveBy()`

Answer (score 7):

Because you call function `moveBy` from itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the function `moveBy` inside the funtion `moveBy`. Whenever you execute the function you call it again and again ...

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    var window;

    function moveBy() {
        alert("-- hello ---");
        window = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
        //window.moveBy(10, 20);
    }
</script>


</head>
<body>
<input type = "submit" value = "moveBy" onclick = "moveBy()"> </input>
</body>
</html>
```