# Using the same function in its function definition?

Tags: c++, c, recursion

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am pretty new to programming.
I've been studying sorts, and merge sort has been giving me a headache.

```
void part(int arr[],int min,int max)
{
 int mid;
 if(min<max)
 {
   mid=(min+max)/2;
   part(arr,min,mid);
   part(arr,mid+1,max);
   merge(arr,min,mid,max);
 }
}
```

I dont understand how you can use the function part in its own definition when it's not even defined fully yet. Also, I dont really quite understand how this is working.. Please help me understand this!!

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: http://cprogrammingcodes.blogspot.com/2012/02/merge-sorting.html
Here is full code just in case you want to see..

Comment: Check out [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Comment: ahhh that's what I assumed but was too afraid to accept it... sigh.. Time to dig it then. Thank you.

Comment: Can you express in a better manner?. ..function part in it's own definition???

Comment: The function is calling itself. At the point where you write `part(arr,min,mid);`, the `part` function is known to the compiler, therefore it can be called thithout problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is recursion and when should I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: You do use `printf()`?  How do you know it is "defined fully" when you call it?  Code does not know and need not care.  As long is it is _declared_, a function can code with it.  Of course eventually, it must be defined - someplace.

Answer (score 2):

C++ differentiates between functions being defined and functions being declared, the difference that being to declare a function is just to know it's signature (so `void part(int arr[],int min,int max)`. This is then sufficient information for other parts of the program to call it, without it actually needing a body of code. The definition is then where the code itself is defined.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to call a function is its *declaration*, and a function definition also is an automatic declaration (if not already declared), and all that's needed for this automatic declaration is the function signature (return type, name, arguments, but *not* the full body).

Without this it would be very hard to do [*recursion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29), which is what happens when a function calls itself.