# How does function replace repeated logic in Python?

Tags: python, function

This original code using repeated code

```
movies = ["hello", "take", ["near", "others",["tra", "told", "model"]]]
for each_item in movies:
   if isinstance(each_item, list):
      for nested_item in each_item:
         if isinstance(nested_item, list):
            for deeper_item in nested_item:
               if isinstance(deeper_item, list):
                  for deepest_item in deeper_item:
                     print(deepest_item)
               else:
                  print(deeper_item)
         else:
            print(nested_item)
   else:
      print(each_item)
```

This is without using a function. When I want to condense code by removing the repeated logic, the new code (using a function I call `print_lol`) will be

```
movies = ["hello", "take", ["near", "others",["tra", "told", "model"]]]
def print_lol(the_list):
   for each_item in the_list:
      if isinstance(each_item, list):
         print_lol(each_item)
      else:
         print(each_item)
print_lol(movies)
```

I want to understand `print_lol(each_item)` in the `if` statement. What does it do?  Using `print_lol(each_item)` inside its own function definition made it repeat, but I don't understand how.

Comment: use the `{ }` button or `ctrl+k` to make the selected text into a *block of code* when editing.

Comment: And the term you're looking for is recursion.

Comment: And there is a question on the generic thing, i.e. flattening a list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is recursion and when should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: I want to understand that

Comment: `print_lol()` is a **function**, and `print_lol(each_item)` is repeatedly calling **itself** (the function) with each new `each_item`, but original code has no function, so it **manually** and **explicitly** must handle every `each_item` individually. When the repeating behavior is put into a *function* it is a technique called **recursion** which means **"repeating a function"**, so each time the code encounters the same datatype, it repeats the function, which is what makes it more abbreviated than the original code. Does that make sense?
 Ask more questions if you still do not understand.

Comment: Thank you @downshift for responding and explaining and might understand  it

Comment: Very welcome, @MohamedKhaled, it may still be confusing, ask more questions if we can help explain more

Comment: but in this code `def sum_number(number):
   if number == 0:
      return 0
   else:
      return number + sum_number(number-1)

print(sum_number(3))
`@downshift

Comment: The result is **6** but I'm trying to analyze the code but there is problem