# How can I reset a counter within each subfolder level in a loop that access recursively a parent directory?

Tags: windows, powershell, loops, foreach, automation

I made a script to add a sequential prefix to all folders within a parent folder, but the counter keeps incrementing despite being in a level different than its parent, like...

Testing script:

```ps
# Create sample folders:
ni -path $home\parent_folder -itemtype "directory"
ni -path $home\parent_folder\child_a, $home\parent_folder\child_b -itemtype "directory"
ni -path $home\parent_folder\child_a\grandchild_a, $home\parent_folder\child_b\grandchild_b -itemtype "directory"
ni -path $home\parent_folder\child_a\grandchild_a\n_child_a, $home\parent_folder\child_b\grandchild_b\n_child_b -itemtype "directory"

# Run loop recursively:
dir $home\parent_folder -directory -recurse | foreach -begin { $i = 1 } -process { ren $_.fullname -newname ( "{0}_{1}" -f $i, $_.name ) ; $i++ }

# Print output:
dir $home\parent_folder -recurse | % {""} { write-host $_.fullname } {""} 

# Output:
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a\3_grandchild_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a\3_grandchild_a\4_n_child_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b\5_grandchild_b
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b\5_grandchild_b\6_n_child_b
```

I found two ways to handle this, but none of them are as efficient as I want them to be...

1. Nested foreach loop function (not scalable):

```ps
Function prefix_dir ($parent_dir) # $parent_dir is the path to parent_folder
{
    $i = 1
    foreach ($child_dir in (Get-ChildItem $parent_dir -directory))
    {
        $j = 1
        foreach ($mini_dir in (Get-ChildItem $parent_dir\$child_dir -directory))
        {
            Rename-Item $mini_dir.fullname -newname ( "{0}_{1}" -f $j, $mini_dir.name )
            $j++
        }
    Rename-Item $child_dir.fullname -newname ( "{0}_{1}" -f $i, $child_dir.name )
    $i++
    }
}

# Print output:
dir $home\parent_folder -recurse | % {""} { write-host $_.fullname } {""} 

# Output:
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a\1_grandchild_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a\1_grandchild_a\n_child_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b\1_grandchild_b
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b\1_grandchild_b\n_child_b
```

As you can see from the function above the last level of folders is not affected coz another foreach loop is necessary (with another counter/iterator). I'd have to manually nest loops depending on a folder's levels—clearly not worthy.

2. The other way is just to omit the recurse parameter in the first loop (on "testing script") and use cd or sl (aliases for Set-Location) to access each subfolder and run the loop again, only affecting the current directory.

**My goal is to be able to add the prefix to all folders within the given parent folder and reset the counter to 1 in each sublevel.** All in one script, similar to the first loop, recursively. And I know I'm probably missing a big concept here, but I thought it was about time to ask for help.

My desired output would be:

```ps
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a\1_grandchild_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\1_child_a\1_grandchild_a\1_n_child_a
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b\1_grandchild_b
C:\Users\victo\parent_folder\2_child_b\1_grandchild_b\1_n_child_b
```

Comment: Your ```prefix_dir``` function needs to do 2 things (i) rename the *immediate* subfolders of ```$parent_dir```, (iii) invoke itself for each immediate subfolder, passing the subfolder path as the ```$parent_dir``` parameter to descend the directory structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the helpful comment from [**mclayton**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton), you might create a [recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3093/1701026) to deal with this:

```
Function prefix_dir($Folder = '.') {
    $Folder = Get-Item $Folder
    $Index = 1
    Get-ChildItem -Directory $Folder | ForEach-Object {
        prefix_dir $_
        Rename-Item -WhatIf $($_.FullName) "$Folder\$($Index)_$($_.Name)"
        $Index++
    }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't even think of calling the function inside the loop. It's simpler and thus smoother, glad both of you @mclayton introduced me to the concept. I'll go deeper on it.