JS - recursive function on multidimensional array to filter out only "checked" items (and its parents if a child is selected)
I have this kind of array (i call it categories, these have childCats too)
var cats = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "A",
      "parentCategoryId": null,
      "parentCategory": null,
      "childCategories": [
          {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "B",
              "parentCategoryId": 1,
              "parentCategory": null,
              "childCategories": [
                  {
                      "id": 3,
                      "name": "C",
                      "parentCategoryId": 2,
                      "parentCategory": null,
                      "childCategories": []
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 4,
                      "name": "D",
                      "parentCategoryId": 2,
                      "parentCategory": null,
                      "childCategories": []
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 5,
                      "name": "E",
                      "parentCategoryId": 2,
                      "parentCategory": null,
                      "childCategories": []
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": 66,
      "name": "BLA",
      "parentCategoryId": null,
      "parentCategory": null,
      "childCategories": []
  },  
  
];

What i now need is to get an array with checked items (and its parents)
This means, i checked only "C", i get:
[
  {
      "name": "A",
      "childCategories": [
          {
              "name": "B",
              "childCategories": [
                  {
                      "name": "C",
                      "childCategories": []
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  }
]

if i checked "C" and "D":
var cats = [
  {
      "name": "A",
      "childCategories": [
          {
              "name": "B",
              "childCategories": [
                  {
                      "name": "C",
                      "childCategories": []
                  },
                  {
                      "name": "D",
                      "childCategories": []
                  }
              ]
          }
      ]
  },    
];

and for "B" this:
var cats = [
  {
      "name": "A",
      "childCategories": [
          {
              "name": "B",
              "childCategories": []
          }
      ]
  },    
];


What i currently have (and it feels like a mess) is that: (result in console.log(..))


console.clear();
var checkedInterests = ['C'];
var checkedInterestsForDisplay = [];

var getInterestsForDisplay = function(arr) {
  for (var a of arr) {
    if (checkedInterests.includes(a.name)) {
      a.childCategories = [];
      checkedInterestsForDisplay.push(a);

      //also if a child is checked, the parent should be expanded
      var getParents = function(arrayToFindParent, parentIdToFind) {
        for (var aTFP of arrayToFindParent) {
          if (aTFP.id == parentIdToFind) {
            aTFP.childCategories = checkedInterestsForDisplay;
            checkedInterestsForDisplay = [aTFP];
            //again check if it has parents
            getParents(cats, aTFP.parentCategoryId);
          } else {
            getParents(aTFP.childCategories, parentIdToFind);
          }
        }
      }
      getParents(cats, a.parentCategoryId);
    }
    getInterestsForDisplay(a.childCategories);
  }
}

getInterestsForDisplay(cats);

console.log('checkedInterestsForDisplay', checkedInterestsForDisplay);
<script>
var cats = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "parentCategoryId": null,
    "parentCategory": null,
    "childCategories": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "B",
      "parentCategoryId": 1,
      "parentCategory": null,
      "childCategories": [{
          "id": 3,
          "name": "C",
          "parentCategoryId": 2,
          "parentCategory": null,
          "childCategories": []
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "D",
          "parentCategoryId": 2,
          "parentCategory": null,
          "childCategories": []
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 66,
    "name": "BLA",
    "parentCategoryId": null,
    "parentCategory": null,
    "childCategories": []
  },
];
</script>



this works oky, but if
var checkedInterests = ['C','D'];

i get

Maximum call stack size exceeded


When doing recursive programming, make sure to have a "base case" or "guard case". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it

C and D have the same parent. I don't see how your code ensures that the parent is only included once in the result, with both children.

Here's a simplified recursive approach.  I assume the result should be the same if you check A and C as if you just checked C.


console.clear();
var checkedInterests = ['B','BLA'];

const getInterestsForDisplay = (arr) => 
  arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    // get a list of checked children (recursive call)
    const children = el.childCategories?.length 
      ? getInterestsForDisplay(el.childCategories)
      : [];
    
    // either this element is checked, or a child is checked, to be added to output.  
    if (checkedInterests.includes(el.name) || children.length) {
      acc.push({...el, childCategories: children});
    }
    
    return acc;
  }, []);

const checkedInterestsForDisplay = getInterestsForDisplay(cats);
console.log(checkedInterestsForDisplay);
<script>
var cats = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "parentCategoryId": null,
    "parentCategory": null,
    "childCategories": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "B",
      "parentCategoryId": 1,
      "parentCategory": null,
      "childCategories": [{
          "id": 3,
          "name": "C",
          "parentCategoryId": 2,
          "parentCategory": null,
          "childCategories": []
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "D",
          "parentCategoryId": 2,
          "parentCategory": null,
          "childCategories": []
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 66,
    "name": "BLA",
    "parentCategoryId": null,
    "parentCategory": null,
    "childCategories": []
  },
];
</script>




You could simplify the code to get the items from children, or check the actual root. If either has some wanted items return the object with filtered children.


const
    data = [{ id: 1, name: "A", parentCategoryId: null, parentCategory: null, childCategories: [{ id: 2, name: "B", parentCategoryId: 1, parentCategory: null, childCategories: [{ id: 3, name: "C", parentCategoryId: 2, parentCategory: null, childCategories: [] }, { id: 4, name: "D", parentCategoryId: 2, parentCategory: null, childCategories: [] }, { id: 5, name: "E", parentCategoryId: 2, parentCategory: null, childCategories: [] }] }] }, { id: 66, name: "BLA", parentCategoryId: null, parentCategory: null, childCategories: [] }],
    filter = (data, names) => data.reduce((r, o) => {
        const
            childCategories = filter(o.childCategories, names);
            
        if (names.includes(o.name) || childCategories.length) r.push({ ...o, childCategories });
        
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(filter(data, ['A']));
console.log(filter(data, ['B']));
console.log(filter(data, ['C', 'D']));
console.log(filter(data, ['BLA', 'C', 'D']));
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




One could implement a function which either returns the null value or the recursively created matching part of any processed category item.
A category item qualifies for a match either in case it directly matches a category by name or in case any of its children does, hence its recursively processed childCategories array is not empty.
One in addition would implement a guard which recognizes an initially passed array of (parent) category items and handles this case within an own recursive flatMap based task.
Thus such a function either returns an empty or non empty array of recursively created matching data (sub) structures, or in case of a sole passed category item it does return either null or the recursively created matching (sub) structure of this passed item.


function retrieveMatchingData(sourceData, lookup) {
  // 1st guard, handling an initially passed source data array.
  if (Array.isArray(sourceData)) {

    return sourceData
      .flatMap(parentData =>

        // ... diving into recursion ...
        retrieveMatchingData(parentData, lookup) ?? []
      );
  }
  // 2nd guard, handling an not provided category lookup.
  if (!lookup) {
    return null;
  }

  // implementation of the recursive creation
  // of any matching category data item.

  const { childCategories, ...rootData } = sourceData;

  const matchingChildList = childCategories
    .reduce((categoryList, childData) => {

      const categoryMatch =
        // ... diving into recursion ...
        retrieveMatchingData(childData, lookup);

      if (categoryMatch !== null) {

        categoryList.push(categoryMatch);
      }
      return categoryList;

    }, []);

  // assembling and returning the result of each recursion.

  return (

    lookup.has(rootData.name) ||
    matchingChildList.length >= 1

  ) && {

    ...rootData,
    childCategories: matchingChildList,

  } || null;  
}

const cats = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "A",
  parentCategoryId: null,
  parentCategory: null,
  childCategories: [{
    id: 2,
    name: "B",
    parentCategoryId: 1,
    parentCategory: null,
    childCategories: [{
      id: 3,
      name: "C",
      parentCategoryId: 2,
      parentCategory: null,
      childCategories: [],
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: "D",
      parentCategoryId: 2,
      parentCategory: null,
      childCategories: [],
    }],
  }],
}, {
  id: 66,
  name: "BLA",
  parentCategoryId: null,
  parentCategory: null,
  childCategories: [],
}];

const result_C_D =
  retrieveMatchingData(cats, new Set(['C', 'D']));

const result_B_BLA =
  retrieveMatchingData(cats, new Set(['B', 'BLA']));

const no_category_match =
  retrieveMatchingData(cats, new Set([]));


const no_category_data =
  retrieveMatchingData(cats[0], new Set([]));

console.log({
  result_C_D,
  result_B_BLA,
  no_category_match,
  no_category_data,
});
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }




I never thought of using Sets, thanks a lot for the clarification!

By building this atop a reusable utility function, we can separate out the general-purpose traversal/filtering of the tree and the mapping of the resulting node from the specific details of testing for matching interests and  choosing only the appropriate fields.


// utility function
const deepFilterMap = (pred, transform, prop = "children") => (xs) => xs .flatMap (
  ({[prop]: cs = [], ...rest}, _, __, kids = deepFilterMap (pred, transform, prop) (cs)
) => pred (rest) || kids.length
  ? [transform (rest, kids)]
  : []
)

// (custom) main function
const mySearch = (interests) => deepFilterMap (
  ({name}) => interests.includes(name),
  ({name}, childCategories) => ({name, childCategories}),
  'childCategories'
)

// sample data
const cats = [{id: 1, name: "A", parentCategoryId: null, parentCategory: null, childCategories: [{id: 2, name: "B", parentCategoryId: 1, parentCategory: null, childCategories: [{id: 3, name: "C", parentCategoryId: 2, parentCategory: null, childCategories: []}, {id: 4, name: "D", parentCategoryId: 2, parentCategory: null, childCategories: []}, {id: 5, name: "E", parentCategoryId: 2, parentCategory: null, childCategories: []}]}]}, {id: 66, name: "BLA", parentCategoryId: null, parentCategory: null, childCategories: []}];

// demo
[['C'], ['C', 'D'], ['B'], ['BLA']]
  .forEach(interests => console.log(JSON.stringify(interests) + ': ', mySearch(interests)(cats)))
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}




deepFilterMap traverses the tree structure.  It first recurs on any children found (stored as kids), and then includes the current node if it matches the predicate supplied or if kids is not empty.  This had to be expanded slightly from my usual version in order to allow for my expected children node name to be configurable for such names as "childCategories".
This function takes a predicate which tests if a node should be included and a function which supplies the object and the list of children, and converts its input structure into the output one.  It also optionally takes a name like "childCategories" if we need to override the default "children".  It returns a function which filters and maps a tree using these input functions.

mySearch is our custom code.  It is a function which takes an array of interests, using it to supply simple functions for the parameters to  deepFilterMap.  It also supplies the override "childCategories".  It gives back the function returned by deepFilterMap.


Such a breakdown is useful.  While we could write this function directly in fewer lines, like this:
const mySearch = (interests) => (xs) => xs .flatMap (
  ({childCategories = [], name}, _, __, kids = mySearch (interests) (childCategories)
) => interests.includes(name) || kids.length
  ? [{name, childCategories: kids}]
  : []
)

instead we can leave the complexities in our library of utility functions, and have much more pleasant custom code such as this:
const mySearch = (interests) => deepFilterMap (
  ({name}) => interests.includes(name),
  ({name}, childCategories) => ({name, childCategories}),
  'childCategories'
)

